# React lazy rendering on slow children

Tags: reactjs

I have a component, which has a super complex graphic child which takes >5s to render. It is not because of the data fetching or bundle size, the rendering really takes long and to optimize it is somehow a mission impossible.

```
<>
  <Other />
  <SlowOne />
</>
```

It is acceptable that the "SlowOne" is slow, what we want to do is:

1. Other parts should be interactable while this one is rendering.
2. Is there a React API to indicate the "mounting", "mounted", "rendering", "render complete" state so that we can show a placeholder before the "SlowOne" mounted.

Any ideas to implement them?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the React.Lazy function and the Suspense component.

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';

const SlowOne = React.lazy(() => import('./SlowOne'));

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Other />
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <SlowOne />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}
```

A "loading" text or container will be rendered in place of the component while it is loading. You can also passed in another component as a fallback.

Or do a conditional render.

```
render() {
  const flag = false;
  return (
    <div>
      { flag && <SlowOne />} // only render if flag is true
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. It won't work. This approach only delays the component's loading, not rendering. Both renderi phases and commit phases of the Slow one take long time and the interaction of the whole page will be blocked.

Comment: You may need to declare a flag or a conditoinal as a state or as a component props and check if the value of that flag or condition is true. If it is not set or is not set to true, do not render the component. More info about conditional rendering here. https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html  and I added an example above.

Comment: Then once the flag becomes true, the slow component start to render and the whole page is not interactable.